# Multiple Concat_WS causing query timeout error

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
SELECT TimeSheetsMain.TimeSheetID,
CONCAT_WS(' ', ForeMan.FirstName, Foreman.MiddleInitial, Foreman.LastName) as ForemanFullName,
CONCAT_WS(' ', Manager.FirstName, Manager.MiddleInitial, Manager.LastName) as ManagerFullName,
CONCAT_WS(' ', Supervisor.FirstName, Supervisor.MiddleInitial, Supervisor.LastName) as SupervisorFullName,
CONCAT_WS(' ', Office.FirstName, Office.MiddleInitial, Office.LastName) as OfficeFullName,
ServiceDate, RoeseJobNumber, CustomerJobNumber,
JobDescription, CustomerName,CONCAT_WS(', ', StreetAddress, City, TownShip) as Address , COALESCE(TotalEmployees,0) as TotalEmployees,
COALESCE(TotalHoursWorked,0) as TotalHoursWorked, TimeSheetStatus
FROM TimeSheetsMain
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT TimeSheetID, COUNT(DISTINCT EmployeeID) as TotalEmployees,Sum(HoursWorked) as TotalHoursWorked
FROM TimeSheetsDetail
WHERE EmployeeID <> -1
GROUP BY TimeSheetID) TimeSheetHours ON TimeSheetHours.TimeSheetID = TimeSheetsMain.TimeSheetID
LEFT JOIN Employees Foreman ON Foreman.EmployeeID = TimeSheetsMain.ForeManID
LEFT JOIN Employees Manager ON Manager.EmployeeID = TimeSheetsMain.ManagerID
LEFT JOIN Employees Supervisor ON Supervisor.EmployeeID = TimeSheetsMain.SupervisorID
LEFT JOIN Employees Office ON Office.EmployeeID = TimeSheetsMain.OfficeID
ORDER BY ServiceDate DESC;
```

I have this which results in a query timeout exception and I was able to figure about that the error is caused by the `CONCAT_WS` statements that I was using to figure out the fullName through trial and error. If I remove any one of the 4 initial `concat_ws` statement the query runs just fine in 0.1 seconds. However, for some reason SQL just does not seem to like having all 4 of them at the same time and I just cannot figure out the reason.

I can leave all of the joins right in there. I just have to remove any of the `CONCAT_WS`like:

`CONCAT_WS(' ', ForeMan.FirstName, Foreman.MiddleInitial, Foreman.LastName) as ForemanFullName`

I also know that this is not caused by some kind of limit on number of `CONCAT_WS` we can use because if I change one of the `CONCAT_WS` to be the same as the other one. Example if I have 2 of the same statements like this:

```
CONCAT_WS(' ', ForeMan.FirstName, Foreman.MiddleInitial, Foreman.LastName) as ForemanFullName,
CONCAT_WS(' ', ForeMan.FirstName, Foreman.MiddleInitial, Foreman.LastName) as ForemanFullName,
CONCAT_WS(' ', Supervisor.FirstName, Supervisor.MiddleInitial, Supervisor.LastName) as SupervisorFullName,
CONCAT_WS(' ', Office.FirstName, Office.MiddleInitial, Office.LastName) as OfficeFullName
```

The result shows up in 0.1 second again

Can someone point me towards somewhere which can help me figure this out?

Comment: Unlikely to be the `concat_ws`, have you tested just including the columns wihout using `concat`, do you see the same behaviour? More likely to be the query optimizer won't be including any `outer join` table in the execution plan if no columns are referenced.

Comment: Please add table and index definitions, and share the query plans for both versions via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan